# Executing onetime scripts from Azure DevOps Pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, devops, continuous-deployment, azure-devops-pipelines

I'm looking for some advice on how others might have managed the handling and execution of one-time scripts which need to be executed either pre-deployment or post-deployment.

We are looking at building a solution but I was wondering if there are any tools out there already?

I want the pipeline to find the scripts which are relevant to the sprint release being deployed and run the script if it has not been run before. These scripts are often data changes following schema updates. We use CosmosDB. Scripts are written in .Net

Comment: We plan to do the same thing. Our solution will be handling it like DB migrations. There will be a table in the DB. There will be a folder in the repository with proper naming conventions for the files and execute only those scripts that are not in the DB list. We are not sure about parameter handling depending on the environment but a solution would be .yaml template file with the scripts and proper parameters depending on the environment.

Comment: @Tom Andrews Did you come up with a feasible solution? I also look for something that has already proven its worth in practice.